# How to trigger code from an exposed COM Interface's method?

Tags: c#, plugins, com

A software that my company uses allows for the creation of a Plugin but the Plugin must be a COM Object and implments the IProfilePlugIn interface show below:

```
namespace profile
{
    [Guid("CE694B21-9547-11D3-8606-BB9193E3F22C")]
    [TypeLibType(192)]
    public interface IProfilePlugIn
    {
        [DispId(9)]
        void AppClose();
        [DispId(8)]
        void AppCloseQuery(ref bool CanClose);
        [DispId(10)]
        void AppIdle();
        [DispId(11)]
        void AppOpen(ref bool ShowQuickStart, ref bool Continue);
        [DispId(3)]
        void ClientNotification(IProfileClient ProFileClient, string FileName, string ClientID, int Action, ref int Response);
        [DispId(7)]
        void ExecuteAction(string AActionID, ref bool Handled);
        [DispId(2)]
        void FieldChangeNotification(IProfileClient ProFileClient, int UniqueID);
        [DispId(4)]
        int GetAboutBoxBitmap();
        [DispId(15)]
        void GetEncryptionType(ref int EncryptionType);
        [DispId(14)]
        void GetLicenseCode(ref string LicenseCode);
        [DispId(13)]
        void GetLicenseName(ref string LicenseName);
        [DispId(6)]
        IProfileDialog GetProfileDialog();
        [DispId(5)]
        int GetSplashBitmap();
        [DispId(1)]
        void Initialize();
        [DispId(12)]
        bool RTUNotification(IProfileClient ProFileClient, int RTUType, out string AError);
    }
}
```

There is a method AppOpen(ref bool ShowQuickStart, ref bool Continue); which is executed when the program first opens.  How do a for example pop a message box open during that method without having to implement all of the other methods?

As far as I understand I have to create a ClassLibrary in VS and then mark is as a ComVisible and inherit from the interface and add the GUID attribute and ClassInterfaceType but that is where I get lost.

I know once this is created I have to register the COM object and perform some registry changes for the Program to consume the plugin.

What do I need to do in order to make MessageBox.Show("Test"); execute during the AppOpen method?

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to do in order to make MessageBox.Show("Test"); execute during the AppOpen method?

```
void AppOpen(ref bool ShowQuickStart, ref bool Continue)
{
    MessageBox.Show ("Test");
}
```

Comment: So literally just need to inherit from that interface and declare my own method?

For methods that I'm not implementing what do I need to do just add the methods with no body?

Comment: 1) Yes.   2) It depends - you would need to refer to their doco. Some methods I see have `ref` parameters which is an indication the plug-in host system will be expecting something from you?  Then again that could apply to any of the methods

Comment: Ok I apologize my terminology is horrible and I am very new to this but my work is making me figure this out.

Becasue I'm using the interface I have to implement all of the methods but just leave the body empty essentially?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's right - as far as .NET is concerned you must at least have an empty body for the `void` methods.  That method returning `bool` must return something though.  That is the minimal you need to do.  Again, refer to the plug-in doco to see which methods really need to _do something_.  Good luck my friend

Comment: Their is basically no documentation or examples it just tells me I need to implement the interface IProfilePlugin in a COM object and then tells me how to make the Program consume the plugin.  Unfortunately they can't afford to hire a professional.

Comment: I understand.  Well see how you go, if something else pops up relevant to your question above update your post else feel free to post a new question.  Good luck!